# jQuery focus() not working (using Firefox 56)

Tags: jquery, firefox

I cannot get jQuery to focus on an input field.  Am I overlooking something obvious here?  This code is not working for me in Firefox 56.  Also in Chrome it's randomly not working - if I blur the field and reload the snippet it does not focus.  Never had this issue before now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#focus').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="focus" />
```

**UPDATE:** Closed browser and reopened and the problem has magically disappeared.  Somehow Firefox lost the ability to respond to this event - I'm chalking this up to either a Browser or Operating System bug.  Leaving the question as it may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: might have been from some interaction with autocomplete.

Comment: maybe, I've found this current version of firefox to be rather tweeky.  but i literally tried everything even firing a manual event and nothing would work in either browser.  I don't really understand the underlying software mechanics of this but the fact the both stopped working makes me think it was an issue with OS X.

Comment: also for the record, I initially had `autocomplete="off"` set.  Unsetting that attribute didn't help.  not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: I guess you aren't just wanting it on page load in your actual implementation so you can't just set the autofocus attribute?

Comment: @abney317 - that's always an option but no, in this particular case it was about doing it in jQuery.  The code snippet was the most simplistic possible example and even the snippet wasn't working in my browsers.  Now it is.  shrug